Intuition behind horizontal and vertical truncation
Context: Tao in 'An Introduction to Measure Theory' defines the unsigned (takes values only in $[0,+\infty]$) Lebesgue integral of a measurable function (ie those functions that are point-wise limits of sequences of unsigned simple functions) to be the lower unsigned Lebesgue integral (ie supremum of the integral of unsigned simple functions that are point-wise bounded by the function we are integrating). By unsigned simple functions we mean those functions $\mathbf R^d\to [0,+\infty]$ that are expressible as finite $[0,+\infty]$-linear combination of indicator functions of subsets of $\mathbf R^d$. Lastly, integral of simple functions is just the sum of the weighted (by the scalars in the linear combination) measures of the subsets of the finitely many indicator functions in any representation of the simple function in question.
Problem: Later there is discussion that the unsigned Lebesgue integral satisfies what he calls as horizontal truncation and vertical truncation, ie,
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_{\mathbf R^d}\min(f(x),n)dx=\int_{\mathbf R^d}f(x)d,$$
and,
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_{\mathbf R^d}f(x)1_{|x|\leq n}dx=\int_{\mathbf R^d}f(x)dx,$$
respectively.
Before trying to prove them I wanted to attempt to understand why they are called as they are. I made some low-dimensional examples to visualize, but didn't get much beyond drawing the image for horizontal truncation.
Question: I would like to understand a rough idea/intuition about what they mean/convey and/or why they are called so. Would be grateful for some help :)

I'm having the same problem right now. The interpretation gets complicated, because there must be a typo in the book, because in chapter 4 (Exercize 35 printed and 36 pdf) he switches the names for the properties.
I try to give the interpretations in both ways:
.
Assume a simple scenario of $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$.
The function $\min(f, n)$ is the function graph of $f$ truncated in vertical direction (interpretation Ch 4) by a horizontal line (interpretation Ch 3).
With the sets $E_n$ one would identify the intervals $[-n, n]$ on the real line. These sets truncate the function graph in horizontal direction (interpretation Ch 4) by a vertical line (interpretation Ch 3).
I prefer the interpretation from Chapter 4.
